I am writing the code for streaming a mp4 video through websocket
writing the code for streaming a mp4 video  through websocket.
sending chunk data through websocket from server side to client side and in client side want to play that video.
data coming to client side but not playing the video why?
server.js code:
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
    console.log('Client connected');

    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'play.mp4');
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
let count =0
    stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
        ws.send(chunk);
        // if(count<1)console.log(new Uint8Array(chunk) )
        count++;
    });

    stream.on('end', () => {
        ws.close();
    });

    ws.on('close', () => {
        console.log('Client disconnected');
    });
});

console.log('WebSocket server is running on ws://localhost:8080');

index.html code:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>WebSocket Video Stream</title>
</head>

<body>
    <video  id="video" autoplay controls></video>
    <script>
        const video = document.getElementById('video');
        const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

        let mediaSource = new MediaSource();
        let queue = [];
        let sourceBuffer;

        mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', () => {
            try {
                // sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64001e, mp4a.40.2"');
                sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64001e, mp4a.40.2"');

                sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', () => {
                    if (queue.length > 0 && !sourceBuffer.updating) {
                        try {
                            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(queue.shift());
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.error('Error appending buffer in updateend:', error);
                        }
                    }
                });

                sourceBuffer.addEventListener('error', (event) => {
                    console.error('SourceBuffer error:', event);
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error adding SourceBuffer:', error);
            }
        });

        ws.onmessage = (event) => {
            if (!sourceBuffer) return; // Ensure sourceBuffer is defined

            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = () => {
                try {
                    if (sourceBuffer.updating || mediaSource.readyState !== 'open') {
                        return;
                    }

                    const arrayBuffer = reader.result;
                    const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

                    console.log('Received data:', uint8Array);
                    queue.push(uint8Array);

                    if (!sourceBuffer.updating && queue.length > 0) {
                        try {
                            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(queue.shift());
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.error('Error appending buffer:', error);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error processing data:', error);
                }
            };

            reader.onerror = (error) => {
                console.error('FileReader error:', error);
            };

            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.data);
            console.log("eventdata= ",event.data)
        };

        mediaSource.addEventListener('error', (event) => {
            console.error('MediaSource error:', event);
        });

        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
    </script>
</body>

</html> 

at client side data is coming but not playing the video .

video want to play:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KaaBd-orhc-C5Uc1YVaL-QCAdHla6e4e/view?usp=sharing
please download the video from the the link provided then read the video data . don't read video data directly from the link.
if video will be  (video.ts ) file then what i need to change ?.
want to stream through websocket only not any other method.
A Big Thanks for help.

Why are you demanding that you read the stream through Web Socket?  If you just use HTTP(S) straight up, it's simpler, the browser handles all the buffering and everything for you.  There is zero benefit to using Web Socket for this use case.

I haven't tested your code, but the only mistake I can see is that you use:
mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64001e, mp4a.40.2"');

Solution:
Replace codecs="avc1.64001e with codecs="avc1.640820 which is correct for this MP4 file.
mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.640820, mp4a.40.2"');

Hopefully you will now get a picture and sound. Ask anything if it's still got errors.
PS:
To auto-detect the video's codec info, you can try Step 2 of my other answer.
